# catch return value form a php file opened by a form submit

Tags: php

i submit a form in html

```
<form id="register" onsubmit="getRegFormErr()" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="username">
```

now in the register.php file i have returns if somethings went wrong

```
if (!isset($username, $password, $email, $securecode, $acctype)) {
    return INVALID_FORM;
}
```

how do i get the return from the php file to a variable in javascript

i tried with a bit of js but don't work

```
function getRegFormErr() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        url: "php/register.php",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    });
}
```

thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the AJAX, but assuming that is correct and assuming `INVALID_FORM` is defined, you need to **output** the result.  Try:

```
echo INVALID_FORM;
```

Instead of:

```
return INVALID_FORM;
```

Also, in `register.php` you should have something like:

```
define('INVALID_FORM', 'The form was not completed');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tis one
delete the `onsubmit="getRegFormErr()"` from HTML code
and in js code write this

```
$('form#register').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/register.php",
        data: $('form#register').serialize(),
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Your form are targeting instead of using ajax, due to lack of `RETURN FALSE;` and use "POST", Replace:
`<form id="register" onsubmit="getRegFormErr()" method="post">`
By:

```
<form id="register" onsubmit="return getRegFormErr()" method="post">

function getRegFormErr() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", //Use POST
        url: "php/register.php",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    });
return false;
}
```

or (better), use Jquery:

```
<form id="register" method="post">

function getRegFormErr() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", // Use POST
        url: "php/register.php",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    });
    return false;// FALSE
}

$("#register").submit(getRegFormErr);
```

**2)** Use "POST vars", replace:

`if (!isset($username, $password, $email, $securecode, $acctype)) {`

By:

`if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['securecode'], $_POST['acctype'])) {`

Comment: I think you need to serialize the form to send it via ajax, the way I do in my [anwser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24418832/2279200)

Comment: @Athafoud thanks, but my answer to the problem in question was the OP, which is why the shipping be malfunctioning. If you want I edit my question and add this detail, can be? Thank you again.